# Understanding Spring MVC sub-project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have some experience in using Spring MVC framework, however, I still have doubts. As I understand, it is an MVC framework which helps in writing web applications using MVC design pattern.

Now, as I tried to understand it better, I came to know that it basically uses two design patterns: "front controller" followed by "MVC" design pattern`.

The first part I understood, the "front controller" is provided by Spring MVC in the form of `DispatcherServlet` which intercepts all the incoming requests intended for it.

Where is the "MVC framework" in Spring MVC framework? As I understood, it is the developer who writes the controller, model, view. If a developer doesn't write code of, say controller there is nothing this framework provides as controller.

I am having difficulty how does Spring MVC supports the MVC pattern when a developer has to write all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain this by taking Controllers as example.

Yes.**At first glance**, it may seems like Spring is doing Nothing.

It might because of the integration code between application code and framework is reduced by Annotations.So developers just missed to notice that single word "@Controller" and started searching "Where is MVC"?

**Spring 2.5 Controller Sample:**

Because of this "**implements** Controller", Spring's role is **more noticeable** here.

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class HelloController implements Controller {

}
```

**Spring 4 Controller:**

Now the Spring's contribution is **less noticeable/visible**. **More or less** this class **might** looks like our own **plain** java class with**out** any framework.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloWorldController {
```

MVC is an **architectural** pattern which defines the **architecture** of the application components and **interaction (request/data flow)** between those components.

**Always** developers has to write their business/application logic by themselves.

Developers are **extending** **Spring MVC's** Controllers.
Developers are extending **Spring MVC's** Models.
Developers do the **request mapping** between request URLs and controller methods.
But, **how this mapping happens** while a request comes ? - It is the **duty of Spring MVC**, which the application developers no need to bother.

In the plain **Old Servlet days too**, application developers did the mapping by mentioning http method and doGet(), doPost() etc.

Similarly, models are annotated with **@Repository**.
And View is either old days JSP or modern day angular JS...

So, In Short, MVC is there , but **less visible now-a-days**.

I hope this answer gives some insights.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing your understanding, helped in understanding the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private IHomeService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("data", service.getHomeContainer()); // model is just a map...

       //
       // create html response using model + home.jsp
       // former usage: return new ModelAndView("home");
       //
        return "home"; 
    }

}
```

So you don't have to implement the **intern collaboration and life cycle** of `@Controller`, `Model` and `View`. Spring do it for you. You just have to init and call them in a way you see above.

And finally, I belive the main idea and benefit of MVC is divide and conquer:

- Team A developing `@Controller` - Level
- Team B developing `@Service` - Level
- Team C developing View (Html, js)

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing your understanding, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Dispatcher Servlet is the front controller in case of Spring MVC, which intercepts all the URLs to the application. However, you(developer) have to write your own controller to process the request. Front controller is the initial point(thus providing central point of entry to the application) of contact while the controller that the dev writes actually processes the request.

The front controller maps the URL to the correct handler.